# ReactRouter doesn't pass path params to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router-dom in version 4.1.2.

I created this router structure and this component:

```js
class ConversationPane extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
       <div id="conversation-pane">
    <h1>Conversation Pane</h1>
    <h3>{this.props}</h3>
             </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <Route path="/conversation/:id" component={ConversationPane} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
  , document.getElementById('main'))
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

This param :id Never has values inside ConversationPane. this.props is always {}.

[image]

In the URL, the value is there RamiSayar, but in console there no value for this.props.

I don't understand what is going on.

Please, can someone help me with this ? It doesn't seem to be hard, but I really tried and didn't find solution out there.

Comment: You're nesting routes incorrectly for `react-router v4`. `<Route path="/conversation/:id" component={ConversationPane} />` should be in your `App` component. Then wrap your `App` component with the `withTracker` HoC. `import { withTracker } from 'react-router-dom';` and then `export default withRouter(App);`

Comment: You're wonderfully right about this nested route!!! 
I inserted <Route path="/conversation/:id" component={ConversationPane} /> inside App and boom. Now ConversationPane has access to <h3>{this.props.match.params.id}</h3> properly!

Thank you sir!!!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the nested route. It doesn't work this way in v4.

The nested route must be inside the Component above it. So the route for ConversationPane must be inside App Component.

The correct way to do it is like below:

```html
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Route path="/conversation/:id" component="ConversationPane" />
    )
  }
}

class ConversationPane extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.match.params.id)
    return (
       <div id="conversation-pane">
    <h1>Conversation Pane</h1>
    <h3>{this.props.match.params.id}</h3>
             </div>
     )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}></Route>
  </BrowserRouter>
  , document.getElementById('main'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) ?

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class ConversationPane extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
       <div id="conversation-pane">
    <h1>Conversation Pane</h1>
    <h3>{this.props}</h3>
             </div>
     )
  }
}

const ConversationPaneWithRouter = withRouter(ConversationPane);

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter history={browserHistory}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <Route path="/conversation/:id" component={ConversationPaneWithRouter} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
  , document.getElementById('main'))
```

Comment: I tried here with withRouter and I got the error message: 
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}).

From: 
bundle.js:14 Error: Minified React error #31; visit http://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7B%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

It appears this line:
<Route path="/conversation/:id" component={ConversationPaneWithRouter} />

doesn't accept: const ConversationPaneWithRouter = withRouter(ConversationPane) as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the params using ‘this.match.params’. (‘this.match.params.id’ for the id you have set)